# Echo Multidimensional array in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, multidimensional-array, echo

I have a problem with CI. I am new do CodeIgniter, and I think this is going to be an easy answer, but I don't know that.

I have `$results`, which is an array, but with CodeIgniter it is this kind of array, I have send this to views

```
$data['results'] = $this->get_db->getAll();
```

Now on view I have $results, an array, something like this:

```
$results=Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [naslov] => Onama [tekst] => kreni ) )
```

How to echo just [tekst] from array, and nothing more? Something like

```
echo [tekst];
```

Comment: use print_r() to print array

Comment: Ok i know that but i dont want entire array, just one member?

Comment: In view: 
    foreach ($results as $row){
           echo $row->tekst; 
        }

Comment: Ok ,working, write it down that i can voteup, but i think there is a nicer solution for that :(, this way i will always have to do foreach, what if i have several elements :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, the following

```
$results = Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 1 [naslov] => Onama [tekst] => kreni 
    )
)
```

is an array of objects and right now you have only one object in the array, so you can access the first (only one now) object as

```
$row = $result[0];
```

And can echo the `tekst` as

```
echo $row->tekst;
```

But, when you have multiple objects in the array, you can loop it like

```
foreach($results as $row)
{
    echo $row->tekst;
}
```

Comment: Nice works like a charm, but this $row = $results[0] is how to for me more code, can i do it somehow to put it in controller?

Comment: @user2266992, yes, `$this->load->view('viewname', array('tekst'=>$result[0]->tekst))` and in the view `echo $tekst`